# Mouse cursor on VM Ubuntu 22.04.3 is an a square

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

I have tried most all of the fixes I see to get rid of this problem, but as yet haven't found one.  My mouse cursor becomes a little square and I end up having to click outside the VM then on the white border and other places until it finally disappears and returns to the normal mouse cursor.  But a few minutes later it returns and it is becoming increasing annoying to work in the VM.

Comment: This is likely a bug with VirtualBox, not Ubuntu

Comment: It was working for several months and then just suddenly started having the issue.   So, is there a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Switching to 'Ubuntu on Xorg' on login [fixes the issue](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/gnome-classic.html.en):

> 1. You need to have the `gnome-shell-extensions` package installed to make GNOME Classic available.
> 2. Save any open work, and then log out. Click the system menu on the right side of the top bar and then choose the right option.
> 3. A confirmation message will appear. Select Log Out to confirm.
> 4. At the login screen, select your name from the list.
> 5. Click the settings button in the bottom right corner.
> 6. Select GNOME Classic from the list.
> 7. Enter your password in the password entry box.
> 8. Press Enter.