# Cursor on hover becomes some static "preview"

Tags: virtualbox, cursor

I run Ubuntu on VirtualBox. Recently, VirtualBox got stuck, and I had to shut it down without properly shutting down Ubuntu. The next time I logged in, my cursor started to act weirdly. Sometimes, on hover, it becomes a "preview" of something and remains like that.
See the picture:
[My cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss330.png)

Annoying. This is the cursor on hover I presume there's a possible fix, but I'm not that skilled in Linux. Can you suggest a way?

I installed gnome tweaks and gnome extensions to try to change the cursor type to see if that helps reset the behavior somehow...It did not help.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1502456/1004020 I suspect a VirtualBox bug

Comment: Just tried to update VB from 7.0.8 to 7.0.14 to see if it was fixed, but no luck